# Trigger Creation for Duplicate Email on Contact

Tags: apex, trigger, insert

I am trying to create a trigger on contact to prevent duplicate records based on Contact Email. It will not be inserted but a Task instead will be created that there is incoming duplicate. I am new to trigger creation I am not sure where to create this (before insert or after insert?).

And May I know the proper way to create trigger and calling a Class instead for a readable and more easy to use code.

Can any one help me on this? Thank you

Comment: To prevent the insert of the Contact, you would have to raise an error on that Contact record in the trigger (`SObject.addError`). However, depending on how the DML was performed this may cause the whole transaction to be rolled back, which would prevent the Task record from being created. Have your considered using the [standard duplicate matching rule for Contact](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_standard_contact_rule.htm&type=5)?

Comment: The current accepted practice for triggers is to use a trigger framework so that the actual logic isn't in the trigger itself. If you're unfamiliar with triggers though, I probably wouldn't advise trying to do that right now (learn about triggers first, create a few to get familiar with it, _then_ look into using a trigger framework). At any rate, the first thing you should do here is to go through the "Apex Triggers" module on https://trailhead.salesforce.com (trailhead is the better resource for getting familiar with new things).

Comment: The general advice on before vs after trigger is that you use a "before" trigger when you are making changes to the record(s) being triggered, and an "after" trigger for everything else. Since you say you want to create a Task, that'd be a job for an "after" trigger.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF I understand the difference now.